# DateTimePicker Type

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some coding part for get exactly date by counting days.

```
void datecheck()
{
    int result = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out result))// Input format Error
    {
       if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Please enter number of days to count..!");
          return; // return because we don't want to run normal code of buton click
       }
       else
       {
           string m = textBox1.Text;
           int number = 0;
           number = int.Parse(m);
           int X = Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString());
           System.DateTime today = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
           System.TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(X, 0, 0, 0);
           System.DateTime answer = today.Add(duration);
           duetoback.Text = answer.ToShortDateString();
       }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Format..!");
    }
}
```

So this coding give result as ("DD/MM/YYYY")
but I need the result with format as follows

DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")

Help me to debug this and Please give me some comment about this coding part which its better or not

Comment: Sir , what is this format? can you give any example?

Comment: Friday, 29 May 2015

Comment: First, consider what all those `string m = textBox1.Text; int number = 0; number = int.Parse(m); int X = Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString());` are doing (hint: the same thing). Also, you have already parsed it, with result in `int result`. Then, if you want generate a specific format, use `DateTime.ToString([your format])`. You should show a MessageBox in case `int.TryParse` fails (just once, asking to enter the value again).

Comment: Does it help you `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string str = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString()).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");`?

Comment: Unless `duetoback` is another DateTimePicker, then set its Value (not the Text) and modify its CustomFormat property. You also don't need a TimeSpan there, just `DateTime.AddDays()`.

Comment: Sorry, Its gave me same result

Comment: Try this  `var dateAfterAdding = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString()));
 duetoback.Text = dateAfterAdding.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));`

Comment: @viveknuna That makes no sense. `DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString())` is `dt`.

Comment: [var dateAfterAdding = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString()));  duetoback.Text = dateAfterAdding.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  ] Can we customize date for (.now)

Comment: @rohit  `Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString())`? First, the text has already been parsed, that's what `intTryParse()` did in the first place, then `m` (besides being useless) it's already a string, so why `string.ToString()`? This is just `duetoback.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(result).ToString([A Format]);`. Unless `duetoback` is a DateTimerPicker itself, then `duetoback.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(result)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking for:

> I need the result with format as follows
>   `DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")`

Then you can try this approach, just pass in any `DateTime` variable into `$"{HERE:FORMAT}";`

```
var now = DateTime.Now; 
Console.WriteLine(now); // 2020-06-06 16:20:02
var formattedNow = $"{now:dddd, dd MMMM yyyy}";
Console.WriteLine(formattedNow); // Saturday, 06 june 2020
```